# How to PgUp/PgDn with SendKeys to a foreground textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, sendkeys

I am trying to page up/down the contents of a simple textbox control in a simple Windows Form on NET 6.0, but something is wrong. Textbox shortcuts are enabled (probably why `SendKeys.SendWait("^a");` works) and readonly is false.

I have a method (not on the UI thread) that I call to `SendKeys.SendWait("{PgUp}");` to the foreground app (which is both the key sender and textbox (with focus) receiver.

1. If I type PgUp on the keyboard, the textbox pages up as expected.
2. If I `SendKeys.SendWait("^a");`, the textbox selects all text as expected.
3. If I `Sendkeys.SendWait("{PgUp}");`, the textbox adds a blank line to the bottom of the text.

From this I conclude that my code is working because it sends "^a" and the textbox receives it and selects all text. But somehow the textbox does not handle the "{PgUp}" key, even though it does when the PgUp key is sent by the keyboard.

I've read easily a dozen articles and posts on the web and SO that talk about paging using scrolling events, positioning the caret and then scrolling to the caret, and so on. But none of them say anything about why SendKeys(^a) and keyboard PgUp would work but SendKeys.SendWait("{PgUp}") would fail.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and maybe what I need to do (or read) to fix it? Thank you

UPDATE: Jimi asked for some code, so here is the code that I use to send the ^a and the {PgUp} keys. I know this is not on the UI thread because it is executed from a voice-driven recognizer thread. The app is a voice-driven app that displays content in the textbox by textbox.AppendLines calls. I was trying to PgUp and PgDn the multi-line textbox by voice as well.

When I tried to use Send (I normally use .SendWait for everything in other programs), I received the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'SendKeys cannot run inside this
> application because the application is not handling Windows messages.
> Either change the application to handle messages, or use the
> SendKeys.SendWait method.'

It is true that my app does not intercept Windows messages. I can't figure out why the app can receive and properly process my keyboard keys, and my "^a' shortcut keys, but not the SendWait("{PgUp}") key.

```
  internal static void
    HelperPageUp() {
    var keys = "{PgUp}";
    keys = "^a";
    SendKeys.SendWait(keys);
  }
```

I'm starting to think that {PgUp} is never handled by a textbox or control. Instead, probably {PgUp} must be handled by logic in a case statement that converts PgUp "orders" into sets of actions that implement whatever PgUp means to the app that receives the PgUp key. So maybe I will have to add a keystroke handler to the form.  Maybe something like this:

```
textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    // identify the special key and implement what it means
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageDown) {
       ...
       e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: To say what's wrong, you'll have to post some code that explains what *I have a method (not on the UI thread)* and  *the foreground app (which is both the key sender and textbox (with focus) receiver* mean. Because these two sentences seem to contradict each other. -- `{PGUP}` works by the way (assuming  the control can scroll). -- Do you have a specific reason to use `.SendWait()` and not `.Send()`? More in general, what is the actual purpose? Just testing or trying to *automate* another app?

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for reading my question. Sorry about the code - I thought it would be pretty useless to everyone so I did not bother to post it. I posted the error message if I try to use Send(). The same app holds the textbox and sends the keys. The SpeechRecognizer receives my voice and calls the HelperPageUp method shown above. It should send some keys to the foreground app (itself) and they should appear in the textbox (which has the focus).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my thought at the end of the question was correct. The ^a was handled by the textbox because I had `textbox.EnableShortcuts=true;`, so the textbox handled the popular ^a shortcut. But keys like {PgUp} are a different matter; they are not included in shortcuts.

The solution was to write code to handle the {PgUp} key explicitly in the form. Here is my code that worked.

```
void
    textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp) {
      // page the viewport up; watch for end of content
      var charIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;
      var lineIndex = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(charIndex);
      // move 20 lines up, but not past zero
      var newLine = lineIndex - 20;
      var newIndex = Math.Max(0, newLine); 
      // set the new anchor and scroll to it
      var newAnchor = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(newIndex);
      textBox1.Select(newAnchor,0);
      textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
      e.Handled = true;
    }
```